# Get db path outside of web app folder on server using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, connection-string

I published a web app to a server and I would like to access a database file (.mdb) that is also stored on the server in a different location outside of mine. How can I do this in the web.config file of my Asp.Net app?

```
<add name="MyOleDbConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= **{?}** \inventory.mdb"/>
```

Comment: Can you define "outside of mine"? Do you mean that it's outside  the root of the web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it from code, using anything like Server.MapPath() - and for good reason.  This would allow developers to write apps that take over host operating systems on cloud servers.  You're restricted from determining the path of files/folders outside of the control of IIS to prevent directory traversal attacks.

You'll need to ask a SysAdmin, or someone who has access what the path is on that machine.  Once you have the full path, you can set the full path in the .config

```
c:\path\inventory.mdb
```

instead of

```
\inventory.mdb
```

You will also need to make sure that the SysAdmin grants you permissions to access the .mdb.

Comment: My project is currently in a virtual directory and the .mdb file is in a directory outside of my virtual directory.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I called the SysAdmin and they gave me the complete path ouside the virtual folder.